# Is it possible to get the source code of a Sharepoint 2010 webpart from just its wsp file?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

If I have just a wsp file of a Sharepoint 2010 webpart, is it possible getting its source code, in a way I can open it in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: What type of webpart it is. Standard web part or the visual web part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .wsp is actually a .cab file. Inside the cab file you should find the .dll you want to decompile as well as any .ascx files. Using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) you might be able to decompile the .dll file.